# Firebase Database Advanced Querying Option

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my data structured as below. Essentially, I have created a "Followers" category as a child of each key, where a key represents a Poll. If the current user ID of my app is listed in the "Followers" category, I want that node to be relevant for my query. Otherwise, I want it ignored.

Would this type of query be possible? I am starting at my top level, "Polls," and then I have to iterate through each child key, then within that key the "Following" child:

```
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Polls");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This kind of query is possible.

You just need to look at each Poll Object and see if the user_ID you are looking for exists in the followers list.

The other solution is to keep a Followers node that links followers to the polls they follow based on user_ID.

This is described in further detail here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures

If the data is instead split into separate paths, also called denormalization, it can be efficiently downloaded in separate calls, as it is needed. Consider this flattened structure:

```
{
  // Chats contains only meta info about each conversation
  // stored under the chats's unique ID
  "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Conversation members are easily accessible
  // and stored by chat conversation ID
  "members": {
    // we'll talk about indices like this below
    "one": {
      "ghopper": true,
      "alovelace": true,
      "eclarke": true
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Messages are separate from data we may want to iterate quickly
  // but still easily paginated and queried, and organized by chat
  // conversation ID
  "messages": {
    "one": {
      "m1": {
        "name": "eclarke",
        "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875337
      },
      "m2": { ... },
      "m3": { ... }
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, it sounds like I do not have the optimal data structure. I have thought of this, however I envision users constantly "voting" and writing to the Polls database, therefore I listen in that database as well. I haven't really found a way to "denormalize" the data structure. How would I create the query under my current structure? I am having some issues determining what the actual Query code would look like.

Comment: I am not certain this is the most efficient, but the actual query would be like: Create PollResult List Get all polls -> for each poll go through all of the followers -> if the follower you are looking for is in the list of followers for the poll, add poll to PollResult List. Once you have gone through all the polls, you should have all the polls the specific user was following.

Comment: Got it - so I need to copy the node? I am still confused about the actual code. I do appreciate the help.

Comment: Your initial query is correct, you just need to look through all of the polls. Querying firebase is not that efficient, that is why they recommend structuring your data for faster retrieval if necessary.

Comment: Here is what it looks like for an app that searches through events (in your case this would be polls) for search terms. You would be searching for a user_ID instead of a user provided word: https://github.com/Austin-Android/austin-feeds-me/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/austindroids/austinfeedsme/common/EventsPresenter.java#L174